# Starting with bash: -lt and -gt arguments

Tags: bash, shell, test

I'm starting with bash and I found the following:

```
if test $first -lt $second
then
  echo $first is lower than $second
else
  if test $first -gt $second
  then
    echo $first is higher than $second
  else
    echo $first and $second are equals
  fi
fi
```

For reading the script and executing it, I know what it does, but not what -lt and -gt are for.

Can somebody tell me what is the name of that kind of 'tool' and what they(-lt and -gt) do? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I feel worth pointing out that the `echo` statements in the code answer your question.

Comment: There are missing quotes around the variables

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's short for `less than` and `greater than`. It's used for integer comparison in bash. You can read more by typing `man test`:

```
   ....
   INTEGER1 -gt INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is greater than INTEGER2
   ....
   INTEGER1 -lt INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is less than INTEGER2
   ....
```

Answer (score 11):

You can find the definition of `-lt` and `-gt` in the documentation of the [`test` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) (`man test`), or in the documentation of bash since `test` is a built-in command in bash (like in most other shells).

`-lt` and `-gt` are numeric comparisons (less-than [and not equal], greater-than [and not equal]). There are also less/greater-or-equal operators `-le` and `-ge`, and equal and not-equal operators `-eq` and `-ne`. These are numeric operators, so there will be an error if either side isn't a number, and `9` is considered less than `10`.

The reason names like `-lt` are used rather than the usual `<` is that the character `<` would be interpreted as a redirection. The operators `=` and `!=` also exist, but they perform a string comparison: `test 00 -eq 0` is true whereas `test 00 = 0` is false.

Some shells, including bash, also have operators `<` and `>` which perform a string lexicographic comparison, so `test 9 \< 10` is false because `9` is sorted before `1` (the backslash prevents the character `<` from being interpreted as a redirection operator). These shells also offer the double-bracket syntax for tests, e.g. `[[ 9 < 10 ]]` (as opposed to `[ 9 \< 10 ]`), which can't have redirections inside so the `<` doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 4):

These are comparison operators

-lt = less than

-gt = greater than

You can check this page for further details:

> http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 3):

They are just operators.

Simply:
`gt` and `lt` mean > (greater than) and < (less than).

You can look [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for more information on operators: